# Finding a polynomial in $K[X,Y]$ with $(a^2+1,a^3+a)$ as the only zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, roots

I am working on the following exercise:

> Let $K$ be a field and let $a \in K$. Find a polynomial $P \in K[X,Y]$ such that $(a^2+1,a^3+a)$ is the ***only*** zero of $P$.

So far I have found the following

$$P := XY-(a^2+1)(a^3+a)$$

This almost works, but due to commutativity it still has $(a^2+1,a^3+a)$ and $(a^3+a,a^2+1)$ as zeroes. Could you please give me a hint for another polynomial?

Comment: If $K$ is algebraically complete (for example if $K = \mathbb{C}$), then it's impossible to find any single polynomial with only one zero.  On the other hand, in the case $K = \mathbb{R}$, for example $P := (X - (a^2+1))^2 + (Y - (a^3+a))^2$ will work.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but could you please explain why algebraic closedness excludes there being just one zero for any single polynomial? I do not see why this should be the case

Comment: For each value $y=y_0,$ the polynomial $p(x,y_0)$ in $x$ must have a root, or it must be a non-zero constant polynomial.

Comment: Your polynomial doesn’t come even close to working. First, what if $a^2+1=0?$ But in general, $(b(a^2+1),b^{-1}(a^3+a))$ works for $b\in K\setminus\{0\}.$

Comment: The proof I can think of is: if $P$ had a single zero $a, b$, i.e. $Z(\langle P \rangle) = Z(\langle X-a, Y-b \rangle)$, then by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz that means that $\langle P \rangle$ and $\langle X-a, Y-b \rangle$ would have the same radical ideal.  Thus, we must have $P$ divides $(X-a)^n$ for some $n$, and also $P$ divides $(Y-b)^m$ for some $m$.  That contradicts the fact that $K[X,Y]$ is a UFD and $X-a, Y-b$ are irreducibles that don't differ by a unit.

Comment: If, by some chance, the problem actually meant for you to find a polynomial $P$ such that the zero set of $P$ is exactly $\{ (a^2+1, a^3+a) \mid a \in K \}$, then you could start by noting that except for a few points, $a = Y/X$, so $X = (Y/X)^2 + 1 \implies Y^2 - X^3 + X^2 = 0$.  It would be up to you to show the converse happens: if $Y^2 - X^3 + X^2 = 0$, then there exists $a \in K$ such that $(X,Y) = (a^2+1, a^3+a)$.  (Except even then, there is an issue with $(0,0)$ being in the zero set of $P$, but not in the other set if $K$ has no square root of $-1$.)